# Appropriate way to calculate cross-validated R square

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-squared

I have a dataset that I divide into two equal partitions A and B.

I estimate a regression model on partition A.

I want to calculate the cross-validated $R^2$ when predicting the values in partition B.

I would like to know if the following approach is correct and also what other ways there could be:

```
#generate data:

data <- replicate(10, rnorm(100))
data <- as.data.frame(data)

#divide into training and test set:

train <- data[1:50,]
test <- data[51:100,]

#fit model and get predictions for unseen data:

model <- lm(train[,1] ~., data = train)
predictions <- predict(model, test)

#obtain cross-validated R squared:

cor(predictions,test[,1])^2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is incorrect because it allows for recalibration of predictions with a new overall slope and intercept.  Use this formula after freezing all coefficients: 1 - (sum of squared errors) / (sum of squares total).  The denominator is $(n-1)\times$ the observed variance of $Y$ in the holdout sample.  When you do it correctly you can get negative $R^2$ in some holdout samples when the real $R^2$ is low.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So the correct formula is 1-(sum((data[,1] - predictions)^2) / (n-1) * var(test[,1]) ?

Comment: p.s. what do you mean by freezing all coefficients?

Comment: (+1) "Freezing" means you don't get to refit your model on the test set.  The test set is a proxy for any additional data to which you would like to apply the model you have--which at this stage is the one fit only on the training data.  (I have recently discovered, by observing what my own students do, that the misconception reflected in this question is a common one. I found that displaying a plot of predicted vs. actual values for the test set and discussing its construction could alleviate this confusion.)

Comment: @whuber: I don't get it. Why does my approach allow for recalibration of predictions? I am estimating the model on one partition and using it to predict unseen data. Can you please clarify which part of my approach is incorrect? Thank you!

Comment: I think you're right: I was responding to this answer, rather than reading your code.  (As a general principle, when key parts of a question are buried in code, they tend to get overlooked.)  The code applies the training model to predict the test data and outputs the squared correlation between the predictions and values, as it ought.  You should be concerned about the sensitivity of your approach to outlying data, though. Why don't you just report some measure of the typical prediction error made on the test set?

Comment: thanks. you mean why not use mean squared error? sure I would also use that approach but I want to compare my results to a study that uses "validated R squared". Still I'm wondering: why did @Frank Harrell say that my approach is incorrect?

Comment: So it sounds like your code is correct, but there is disagreement on the calculation of R-squared. @Frank Harrell, could you explain how recalibration arises in the original strategy. It seems the coefficients were developed only on training  data. And am I interpreting whuber's comment correctly that R-squared is not a typical performance measure in this context. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify: I would like to know whether using cor(predictions,test[,1])^2 is appropriate for getting the "validated R squared". I don't understand Frank Harrell's explanation of why it is incorrect.

Comment: It is **very** incorrect.  Say your predictions are off by a multiple of 2 and an additional increment of 10.  The correlation coefficient will not penalize for that, internally allowing for a new slope and intercept to be estimated on top of the predictions.  A correlation is a relative measure whereas sum of squared errors is absolute.

Comment: THanks for clarifying. Is this formula correct then? 1-(sum((data[,1] - predictions)^2) / ((n-1) * var(test[,1]))

Comment: 1 - sum of squared prediction errors / sum of squares of actual Y around its mean, all in the test sample.  Prediction error = $Y - \hat{Y}$.  The denominator is $n-1\times var(Y)$.

Comment: One final question: is there a way to rescale this value so that it goes from 0 to 1?

Comment: What?  Now you want it not to be $R^2$?  $R^{2} < 1$ is needed, to signal predictions _worse_ than random.

Comment: When I estimate the model on a really small sample the R^2 I get can take very large negative values (e.g. -10) is there no theoretical lower bound?

Comment: Correct.  This may lead to advantage of computing the median $R^2$ over cross-validations vs. using the mean.