Regression metrics calculation for each fold vs calculation at the end of k-fold cross validation
I stumbled upon a small realization while I was calculating fit metrics during k-fold cross-validation. Please refer to the following images:
The approach of calculating R² or other fit metrics for each fold:

The approach of calculating fit metrics at the end after collecting the predictions:

For classification accuracy, I could see that this would not be a problem, since calculating accuracy is the count of correctly predicted divided by the total number of observations. Averaging the classification accuracy for each fold is guaranteed to be equivalent to the classification accuracy calculated at the end of predicting the class for each fold.
For regression, fit metrics are numerical and I assume that their average is not equivalent. I have tried a practical example with two datasets and have seen that calculating the fit metrics at the end usually gives better results (e.g., higher goodness of fit) than averaging the results of each fold.
Can someone please give me some hints? I tried seeing the history here and I couldn't find a similar question. Google didn't lead me anywhere, and in fact, I managed to find examples applying both approaches.
Mathematically, what would be the correct way?

Assuming validation sets are of similar sizes, you can compute the metric and then average over the metrics.  No need to concatenate predictions.

@DemetriPananos thanks for the comment, I managed to find a well-answered post that I flagged as a duplicate

or this even: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129937/how-to-compute-r-squared-value-when-doing-cross-validation
